# SimpleXMLElement Returns null on 600dpi background

Tags: php, xml, svg, simplexml, dpi

I have went through a lot of similar questions.i couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I have an `svg image`.I'm trying to get contents from it by using `SimpleXMLElement`.

```
    $svgimage =  path to svg image;
    $svgString=file_get_contents($svgimage) ;//returns image    

    $svg = new SimpleXMLElement( $svgString );//returns nothing
```

I have been using a `300dpi` image as background of svg image.Now i changed it to `600dpi`.After that `$svg` returns nothing.I have no idea why SimpleXMLElement doesn't work on 600dpi.

> **Error Log**
>   Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 29: parser error : AttValue length too long
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():
>   xlink:href="data:image/x-ms-bmp;base64,Qk1mDokAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAZQgAAHEFAAAB
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 29: parser
>   error : attributes construct error
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 29: parser
>   error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag image line 20
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 709: parser
>   error : internal error: Huge input lookup
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():
>   name="order-id"

```
Size of SVG is 12MB
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does any error/exception get shown or written to error log? How big is the SVG file? You could be reaching `memory_limit` with 600 dpi (just a wild guess).

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i have resolved this issue.

```
simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE)
```

LIBXML_PARSEHUGE was it! I don't know how, but I missed it earlier.